# Rxjava use Zip operator

Tags: java, rx-java

i am using zip to merge 2 Observable with following code

```
 Observable<boolean> one = someMethod();
 Observable<String> two = someMethod2(),
 Observable.zip(one, two, 

new Func2<boolean, String, newPojo>() {

  @Override
  public MyResult call(boolean ix, 
      String asd) { 
      return myResult;
     }
  }
 )
```

this work perfectly . but now i want to do if

```
Observable<boolean> one = someMethod();
```

one return true then only make two call otherwise dont make any  two call .
how i can do this ?

Comment: `zip()` will always iterate in parallel, afaik

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatMap`:

```
one.flatMap(bool -> {
    if (bool) {
        return two;
    }
    return Observable.empty();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `filter` and `flatMap` would do it

```
one.filter(aBoolean -> aBoolean)
      .flatMap(aBoolean -> two)
      .subscribe(theString -> {});
```

a solution with zipWith()

```
one.filter(aBoolean -> aBoolean)
     .zipWith(two, (aBoolean, s) -> myResult)
     .subscribe(thePojo -> {});
```

Comment: but then i want both one and two value also

Comment: when two will get trigger

Answer (score 0):

Zip operator is used for making parallel calls.
You can make your one function return an Empty observable instead of false and then apply switchIfEmpty() for executing Observable two.

```
one
.switchIfEmpty(two)
.subscribe()

Observable<Boolean> one = someMethod(){
//your code
if(condition == true){
return Observable.just(true)
}
else{
return Observable.empty()
}

}
```